# TeamCity: different branches on different repos on the same build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I have two different VCS roots configured in TeamCity (9.1.4) with master as default and also `+:refs/pull/(*)/head` in other branch specification.

Now I have a build configuration that uses both repositories.

Building master works just fine but if you try to build a specific pull request/other branch then TC will check the same branch for both repositories.

I know I can add a different VCS with only master and use it for that configuration but is there a way to specify different branches for different repositories on the same build configuration?